# Query regarding binding the label in gridview ItemTemplate to String

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a nested gridview lets call parent gridview as gridview1 and child gridview as gridview2.

For each parent gridview's (gridview1) row i'm adding child gridview (gridview2) depending upon the invoice number that is present on that particular row in the gridview1. Here is a screen shot of that output [here](http://postimage.org/image/2ie31u0pw/).

Inside the child gridview (i.e., gridview2) i have a download linkbutton which i add through item template and software title which i databind to gridview2 after filtering the output that i get through List<>. But as you can see the download linkbutton is being rendered first and then software titles next. But i want the software titles to be rendered first and download link button as last column in child gridview (i.e., gridview2).

Here is the code in .aspx page for nested gridviews. I got a suggestion from a fellow member of this forum that I can add label before the download link button and associate it with data source. I just could n't understand it. How can one do that ?

```
 <asp:GridView ID="UserTransactionGridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" OnRowDataBound="UserTransactionGridView_RowDataBound"
    HorizontalAlign="Center" AllowPaging="true">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Date Of Transaction" HeaderText="Date Of Transaction"
            SortExpression="Date Of Transaction" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Invoice Number" HeaderText="Invoice Number" SortExpression="Invoice Number"
            ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="totalAmount" HeaderText="Total Amount" ReadOnly="True"
            SortExpression="totalAmount" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <asp:Label Text="Software Title" ID="softwareLbl" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:GridView ID="gridView2" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Left" GridLines="None"
                    ShowHeader="false">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-Width="100px">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="DownloadLbtn" Text="Download" runat="server" OnClick="DownloadLbtn_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:componentConnString %>"
    SelectCommand="SelectUserPreviousHistory" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="xyz" Name="userName" Type="String" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

By the way here is the code where i'm binding child gridview with datasource (which is arraylist that i filter based on the invoice number present on the parent gridview (i.e., gridview1)).

```
 protected void UserTransactionGridView_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            GridView gridView2 = (GridView)e.Row.FindControl("gridView2");
            System.Data.DataRowView dr = (System.Data.DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem;
            gridView2.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
            String x = dr[1].ToString();
            softwareTitlesList = SoftwareListRetrieve();
            ArrayList titles = new ArrayList();
            foreach (SoftwareTitles softwareTitle in softwareTitlesList)
            {
                if (softwareTitle.InvoiceNumber.Contains(x))
                    titles.Add(softwareTitle.SoftwareTitle);
            }
            gridView2.DataSource = titles;
            gridView2.DataBind();
            softwareTitlesList.Clear();
        }
    }
```

BTW I'm using Visual studio 2008, asp.net/c# and no LINQ in my web application project.
Please help me.

Thank you in anticipation

PS: If some one doesn't like this question u may delete it after getting answered rather than down voting or flagging it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1: Add **AutoGenerateColumns="false"** to your gv2

2: **<%#Container.DataItem %>** just before linkbutton

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridView2" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Left" GridLines="None" ShowHeader="false" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-Width="100px">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%#Container.DataItem %>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="DownloadLbtn" Text="Download" runat="server" OnClick="DownloadLbtn_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

You can add a separate TemplateField instead of adding in same before the existing one but the you get the idea why it is showing next to linkbutton.